# Optimizing JavaScript code that lowercases JSON property names

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer

I working on a web application that receives JSON data with uppercase property names. I need those property names to be lowercase, so I'm using a function to loop recursively through the JSON object and convert them to lowercase.

The problem is my JSON replies can get very large. I want the function to perform well even if it has to process JSON with 60,000 property names and various levels of nesting.

The lowercasing function is:

```
FN = function (obj)
{var ret = null;
    if (typeof(obj) == "string" || typeof(obj) == "number")
        return obj;
    else if (obj.push)
        ret = [];
    else
        ret = {};
    for (var key in obj)
        ret[String(key).toLowerCase()] = FN(obj[key]);
    return ret;
};
```

And I'm performing some benchmarking here: http://jsfiddle.net/emw89/7/

The above test clocks in at ~570ms on my machine.

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this function?

Edit: I closed my IE, re-opened IE and ran the jsfiddle benchmark again--it's now coming in at ~180ms for me. My IE had been open for a couple days straight until just then, so maybe that's what was causing such poor performance. Either way, I'm still interested if there's a way to optimize this function further. Any time extra time spent processing JSON directly adds to the elapsed time of every AJAX request.

Comment: it completes around ~150 ms for me

Comment: 78ms - IE9. Hurray for i7 CPU. Chrome seems about 30% slower. All the expense is in the recursion, so I'm not sure there is much else that can be done.

Comment: Two words: [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/chrome/chromeframe/)

Comment: Could you give a little more context? Why do you need them in lower case? Can't you fix the source of the JSON?

Comment: I just closed/re-opened my IE and the processing time dropped from ~570ms to ~180ms. Maybe having IE opened for a long time can slow down performance... who knows? @Tim The reason I need this function is because I'm pulling data from a strange proprietary backend. This backend serializes record structure data into JSON with all the property names capitalized--no way around it. The alternative to this function is to capitalize all properties in my code as well as client-side templates--but that gets ugly really fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var lowerCache = {};

FN = function (obj)
{
    if (typeof(obj) === "string" || typeof(obj) === "number")
        return obj;

        var l = obj.length;
    if (l) {
        l |= 0;
        var result = [];
        result.length = l;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var newVal = obj[i];
            result[i] = typeof(newVal) === "string" ? newVal : FN(newVal);
        }
        return result;
    } else {
     var ret = {};
     for (var key in obj) {

         var keyStr = typeof(key) === "string" ? key : String(key);
         var newKey = lowerCache[keyStr];
         if (newKey === undefined) {
             newKey = keyStr.toLowerCase();
             lowerCache[keyStr] = newKey;
         }

         var newVal = obj[key];
         ret[newKey] = typeof(newVal) === "string" ? newVal : FN(newVal);
     }
     return ret;
    }
};
```

100% faster.

Comment: hm... if obj is array this code return empty array, or am I mistaken

Comment: This looks like the winner, but I'm going to leave the question unanswered for a little while longer in case another magician comes up with something.

Comment: Did some bugfixes. Still a lot faster.

Comment: Can you tell a little about what data you expect? Will the data have the same key values often? Is the structure regular?

Comment: There's a bit of cruft here: 1) what's that `var a` stuff in the first line? 2) You could add `|| obj.push` to the first `if` statement. 3) `typeof(key) === "string"` will always be true; all keys in JavaScript objects are strings (even in arrays).

Comment: 1) true. This is work in progress ;-) 2) No because we have to recursively walk into array values 3) No: alert(typeof ([1][0]));

Comment: The data will have the same key values often. What you see in my jsfiddle JSON example is very close to what I'll actually be processing. There might be some cases where the JSON has 3-4 levels of nesting.

Comment: The first version forgot to recursively descend into array values.

Comment: Btw most object only have five distinct key values. Is this indended?

Comment: That's not intended--just got lazy with typing out distinct key values. The key values on objects will all be unique--but they'll end up getting repeated through the arrays/nesting.

Comment: Posted new version which caches toLower results.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it with the simple regex replace.

1. Use JSON to convert object to string
2. Replace all properties with the same name just lowercase
3. Convert string again into object

e.g.

```
var obj = { SENAD: "meskin" };

var str = JSON.stringify(obj);

function lCase(xxx)
{
    pattern = /\"([a-z0-9_-]{0,})\"\:/gi;
    return  xxx.replace(pattern, function() { return arguments[0].toLowerCase() });
}
str = lCase(str);

var newObj = JSON.parse(str);
alert(newObj.senad);
console.log(str);
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Depending on the complexity of the JSON I would think this might be preferable. JSON is already a string, so you should be able to skip step #1 (which is the advantage over the other method).

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing large JSON objects with IE (or any other browser - but IE is most likely to spit the dummy) I recommend processing your json/array in chunks.

Good explanation of that process can be found here 
http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html (scroll down to the "Timer Patterns for Yielding" heading)