# How to convert property name to lowercase from object using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code

```
$scope.search={"className":{"Id":"101","Class":"business"}};
```

The above data coming from another control,now i'm accessing Class property like `$scope.search.className.Class;` , But i want convert property Class to lowercase like `$scope.search.className.class;` in angularjs only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON to object with lower case key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697352/how-to-parse-json-to-object-with-lower-case-key)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539574/whats-the-best-way-most-efficient-to-turn-all-the-keys-of-an-object-to-lower

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve it by iterating over the entire object and writing a function to convert all properties to lowercase :

```
for(var prop in obj){
    //Make a new property name with lowercase
    obj[prop.toLowerCase()]=a[s];
    //delete the original property with uppercase name
    delete a[s];
}
```

Keep in mind this will not behave correctly if you have property names in your object with just the case difference like : `{foo:"bar",Foo:"baz"}`