# How to transform all JSON keys to lowercase in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Actually, my requirement is to convert whole JSON(only keys) into lowercase. I tried it's converting only first key of that JSON and it's not converting whole all key. Please have a look the fiddle link or please provide any other ways to do this.

Thanks...

```
var obj = {
  "Collections": {
    "conTainer": {
      "rowSet": [{
        "containerIsArchived": "Null",
        "containerOrderNo": "26",
        "versionNum": "0",
        "containerGlobalUniqueId": "Null",
        "containerIsTenantBased": "true",
        "containerCreatedBy": "user",
        "containerIsDeleted": "false",
        "containerTenantId": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
        "containerLayoutId": "4e13dfcd-cd3b-4a29-81bd-0f73cf9577cf",
        "containerApplicationId": "0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "containerIsActive": "Null",
        "containerHeaderText": "apitest19feb16",
        "containerId": "3745b273-c48d-4c94-b576-3d7aac2f7ac6",
        "containerCreatedUTCDate": "2016-02-19 17:57:51.0"
      }]
    }
  }
};

convertKeysToCamelCase(obj);

function convertKeysToCamelCase(obj) {
  if (!obj || typeof obj !== "object") return null;

  if (obj instanceof Array) {
    return $.map(obj, function(value) {
      return convertKeysToCamelCase(value);
    });
  }

  var newObj = {};
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    key = key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1);
    newObj[key] = value;
  });
  console.log(newObj);
  return newObj;
};
```

Here the Fiddle link: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/du5nfm1L/)

Comment: please add the relevant code to your question, not just a fiddle link

Comment: Did you get an error message telling you to put the code in the question instead of just linking to JS Fiddle? You need to put the code in the question and not just say that a link to JS Fiddle is code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14697508/1982680 check this out

Comment: @DipaliVasani ..In my case JSON differ from that. it has object inside array.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/bHz7x/67/ check this out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below code

```
function ConvertKeysToLowerCase(obj) {
    var output = {};
    for (i in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj[i]) === '[object Object]') {
           output[i.toLowerCase()] = ConvertKeysToLowerCase(obj[i]);
        }else if(Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj[i]) === '[object Array]'){
            output[i.toLowerCase()]=[];
             output[i.toLowerCase()].push(ConvertKeysToLowerCase(obj[i][0]));
        } else {
            output[i.toLowerCase()] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
};
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/du5nfm1L/7/)

Comment: Would only change toLowerCase instead of toUpperCase, to respond to the question, and change the name of the function ConvertKeysToLowerCase to be truthful

Comment: Yeah. I already changed. Thank you very much

Comment: @MarioChueca - Actually one  glitch is there in our coding. It's converting everything to object. I need an actual JSON format as it is with key lower case. here the problem is rowset is an array that is changing to object instead of array of object.

Comment: A warning from a time traveler from 2022: this is only handling the first item in arrays so don't just copy paste this function blindly.

Answer (score 3):

you can have a reference from @Christophe's ***[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14697508/1982680)***

If you can't understand here is the code for you : ***[link](http://jsfiddle.net/dipali_vasani/bHz7x/67/)***

js:

```
var obj = {
  "Collections": {
    "conTainer": {
      "rowSet": [{
        "containerIsArchived": "Null",
        "containerOrderNo": "26",
        "versionNum": "0",
        "containerGlobalUniqueId": "Null",
        "containerIsTenantBased": "true",
        "containerCreatedBy": "user",
        "containerIsDeleted": "false",
        "containerTenantId": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
        "containerLayoutId": "4e13dfcd-cd3b-4a29-81bd-0f73cf9577cf",
        "containerApplicationId": "0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "containerIsActive": "Null",
        "containerHeaderText": "apitest19feb16",
        "containerId": "3745b273-c48d-4c94-b576-3d7aac2f7ac6",
        "containerCreatedUTCDate": "2016-02-19 17:57:51.0"
      }]
    }
  }
};
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
var newJson = json.replace(/"([\w]+)":/g, function($0, $1) {
  return ('"' + $1.toLowerCase() + '":');
});
var newObj = JSON.parse(newJson);
console.debug(newObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea, I hope it's useful.

```
var obj = {
    "containerIsArchived": "Null",
    "containerOrderNo": "26",
    "versionNum": "0",
    "containerGlobalUniqueId": "Null",
    "containerIsTenantBased": "true",
    "containerCreatedBy": "user",
    "containerIsDeleted": "false",
    "containerTenantId": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
    "containerLayoutId": "4e13dfcd-cd3b-4a29-81bd-0f73cf9577cf",
    "containerApplicationId": "0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "containerIsActive": "Null",
    "containerHeaderText": "apitest19feb16",
    "containerId": "3745b273-c48d-4c94-b576-3d7aac2f7ac6",
    "containerCreatedUTCDate": "2016-02-19 17:57:51.0"
  };  

for(var i in obj){
    obj[i.toLowerCase()] = obj[i]; 
    delete obj[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

The last statement prints the object with all keys in lowercase. The idea is to create a ***new key*** -- the lowercase version of any given key --, then get rid of the ***old one***.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the below answer a bit to make it easier to read

```
function convertKeysToCamelCase(obj) {
    var output = {}
    for (var i in obj) {
        var current = obj[i]
        if (isObject(current) || isArray(current)) {
            output[i.toLowerCase()] = convertKeysToCamelCase(current);
        } else {
            output[i.toLowerCase()] = current;
        }
    }
    return output;
};

function isObject(obj) {
    return typeof obj === 'object'
}

function isArray(arr) {
    return Array.isArray(arr)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertKeysToCamelCase(input)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to recurse into the object so that the keys at the lower level are covered. To do this, it would be better to create a copy of the object first and then modify that, like so

```
// create copy of object
var newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
convertKeysToCamelCase(newObj);

function convertKeysToCamelCase(obj) {
    if (!obj || typeof obj !== "object") return null;

    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        return $.map(obj, function(value) {
            return convertKeysToCamelCase(value);
        });
    }

    // manipulates the object being passed in
    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
        // delete existing key
        delete obj[key];
        key = key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1);
        obj[key] = value;
        convertKeysToCamelCase(value);
    });

    return obj;
};
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sbbnmz0b/